# Wix Burn Managed Bootstrapper - No Rollback

Tags: sql-server, wix, rollback, burn

I have a managed bootstrapper to install the SQL Server 2014 Express in silent mode. Installation works fine, but if the user cancel's the setup, then Burn doesn't start a rollback?!

Here's the `Chain` definition:

```
<Chain>
  <ExePackage Id="SQLServer2014SP1_32bit"
              DisplayName="SQL Server 2014 Express SP1 (32 bit)"
              DownloadUrl="https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/D/6/2D6264A9-FA30-4731-920F-F21548052577/DEU/x86/SQLEXPRWT_x86_DEU.exe"
              SourceFile="C:\Test\SQLEXPRWT_x86_DEU.exe"
              Cache="no" Compressed="no" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes"
              InstallCondition="NOT VersionNT64"
              InstallCommand="$(var.SQLServerInstallCommand)"
              RepairCommand="$(var.SQLServerRepairCommand)"
              UninstallCommand="$(var.SQLServerUninstallCommand)">
    <ExitCode Value="3010" Behavior="forceReboot"/>
  </ExePackage>

  <ExePackage Id="SQLServer2014SP1_64bit"
              DisplayName="SQL Server 2014 Express SP1 (64 bit)"
              DownloadUrl="https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/D/6/2D6264A9-FA30-4731-920F-F21548052577/DEU/x64/SQLEXPRWT_x64_DEU.exe"
              SourceFile="C:\Test\SQLEXPRWT_x64_DEU.exe"
              Cache="no" Compressed="no" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes"
              InstallCondition="VersionNT64"
              InstallCommand="$(var.SQLServerInstallCommand)"
              RepairCommand="$(var.SQLServerRepairCommand)"
              UninstallCommand="$(var.SQLServerUninstallCommand)">
    <ExitCode Value="3010" Behavior="forceReboot"/>
  </ExePackage>
</Chain>
```

If the installation gets cancelled (user clicks on the cancel-button in my WPF GUI), I set `e.Result` to `Result.Cancel`:

```
e.Result = Result.Cancel;
```

But nevertheless Burn doesn't start a rollback? What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Here's the burn log:

```
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:11]i001: Burn v3.10.2.2516, Windows v6.2 (Build 9200: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\{29D547AE-EAFB-4EA2-BB8A-C83CC04750C8}\.cr\SQL Setup.exe
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:11]i009: Command Line: '"-burn.clean.room=C:\temp\SQL Setup.exe"'
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:11]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\temp\SQL Setup.exe'
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:11]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\temp\'
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:11]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\SQL_Server_20160202152011.log'
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:11]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Sample Company'
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:11]i000: Loading managed bootstrapper application.
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:12]i000: Creating BA thread to run asynchronously.
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:12]i100: Detect begin, 3 packages
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:12]i000: Setting string variable 'NETFRAMEWORK45' to value '379893'
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:12]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL'
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:12]i000: Setting numeric variable 'SqlInstanceKeyFound' to value 0
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:12]i052: Condition 'SqlInstanceKeyFound' evaluates to false.
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:12]i052: Condition 'SqlInstanceKeyFound' evaluates to false.
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:12]i052: Condition 'SqlInstanceFound' evaluates to false.
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:12]i052: Condition 'NETFRAMEWORK45 >= 379893' evaluates to true.
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:12]i052: Condition 'SqlInstanceFound' evaluates to false.
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:12]i052: Condition 'SqlInstanceFound' evaluates to false.
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:12]i101: Detected package: NetFx452Web, state: Present, cached: Complete
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:12]i101: Detected package: SQLServer2014SP1_32bit, state: Absent, cached: None
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:12]i101: Detected package: SQLServer2014SP1_64bit, state: Absent, cached: None
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:12]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:15]i200: Plan begin, 3 packages, action: Install
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:15]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: NetFx452Web
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:15]i052: Condition 'NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:15]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: SQLServer2014SP1_32bit
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:15]i052: Condition 'VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:15]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: SQLServer2014SP1_64bit
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:15]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_SQLServer2014SP1_64bit' to value 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\SQL_Server_20160202152011_000_SQLServer2014SP1_64bit.log'
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:15]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_SQLServer2014SP1_64bit' to value 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\SQL_Server_20160202152011_000_SQLServer2014SP1_64bit_rollback.log'
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:15]i201: Planned package: NetFx452Web, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:15]i201: Planned package: SQLServer2014SP1_32bit, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:15]i201: Planned package: SQLServer2014SP1_64bit, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:15]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:15]i300: Apply begin
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:15]i010: Launching elevated engine process.
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:15]i011: Launched elevated engine process.
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:20:15]i012: Connected to elevated engine.
[0BC8:0810][2016-02-02T15:20:15]i358: Pausing automatic updates.
[0BC8:0810][2016-02-02T15:20:18]i359: Paused automatic updates.
[0BC8:0810][2016-02-02T15:20:18]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[0BC8:0810][2016-02-02T15:20:18]i362: System restore disabled, system restore point not created.
[0BC8:0810][2016-02-02T15:20:18]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{62333823-3122-40b6-a202-6f914a23324c}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[0684:0628][2016-02-02T15:20:18]i338: Acquiring package: SQLServer2014SP1_64bit, payload: SQLServer2014SP1_64bit, copy from: C:\temp\Setups\SQLEXPRWT_x64_DEU.exe
[0684:0628][2016-02-02T15:20:27]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLastUsedSource' to value 'C:\temp\'
[0BC8:0B80][2016-02-02T15:20:37]i305: Verified acquired payload: SQLServer2014SP1_64bit at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\SQLServer2014SP1_64bit, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\9D828C6F6D284BA117AA80D89FEE94756F39DE4F\Setups\SQLEXPRWT_x64_DEU.exe.
[0BC8:0810][2016-02-02T15:20:37]i301: Applying execute package: SQLServer2014SP1_64bit, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\9D828C6F6D284BA117AA80D89FEE94756F39DE4F\Setups\SQLEXPRWT_x64_DEU.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\9D828C6F6D284BA117AA80D89FEE94756F39DE4F\Setups\SQLEXPRWT_x64_DEU.exe" /ACTION=Install /Q /FEATURES=SQLENGINE,CONN,SSMS,SNAC_SDK /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=BUILTIN\Administrators /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /TCPENABLED=1 /NPENABLED=1 /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /HIDECONSOLE'
[0BC8:0810][2016-02-02T15:23:00]e000: Error 0x80070642: Bootstrapper application aborted during EXE progress.
[0BC8:0810][2016-02-02T15:23:00]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed to execute EXE package.
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:23:00]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:23:00]i319: Applied execute package: SQLServer2014SP1_64bit, result: 0x80070642, restart: None
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:23:00]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed to execute EXE package.
[0BC8:0810][2016-02-02T15:23:00]i351: Removing cached package: SQLServer2014SP1_64bit, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\9D828C6F6D284BA117AA80D89FEE94756F39DE4F\
[0BC8:0810][2016-02-02T15:23:06]w353: Unable to remove cached package: SQLServer2014SP1_64bit, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\9D828C6F6D284BA117AA80D89FEE94756F39DE4F\, reason: 0x80070091. Continuing...
[0BC8:0810][2016-02-02T15:23:06]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{62333823-3122-40b6-a202-6f914a23324c}, resume: None, restart: None, disable resume: No
[0BC8:0810][2016-02-02T15:23:06]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {62333823-3122-40b6-a202-6f914a23324c}
[0BC8:0810][2016-02-02T15:23:06]i352: Removing cached bundle: {62333823-3122-40b6-a202-6f914a23324c}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{62333823-3122-40b6-a202-6f914a23324c}\
[0BC8:0810][2016-02-02T15:23:06]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{62333823-3122-40b6-a202-6f914a23324c}, resume: None, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:23:06]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070642, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:23:09]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x642
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:23:09]i410: Variable: NETFRAMEWORK45 = 379893
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:23:09]i410: Variable: SqlInstanceKeyFound = 0
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:23:09]i410: Variable: VersionNT64 = 6.2.0.0
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:23:09]i410: Variable: WixBundleAction = 5
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:23:09]i410: Variable: WixBundleElevated = 1
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:23:09]i410: Variable: WixBundleLastUsedSource = C:\temp\
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:23:09]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog = C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\SQL_Server_20160202152011.log
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:23:09]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_SQLServer2014SP1_64bit = C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\SQL_Server_20160202152011_000_SQLServer2014SP1_64bit.log
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:23:09]i410: Variable: WixBundleManufacturer = Sample Company
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:23:09]i410: Variable: WixBundleName = SQL Server
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:23:09]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSource = C:\Temp\SQL Setup.exe
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:23:09]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder = C:\Temp\
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:23:09]i410: Variable: WixBundleProviderKey = {62333823-3122-40b6-a202-6f914a23324c}
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:23:09]i410: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_SQLServer2014SP1_64bit = C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\SQL_Server_20160202152011_000_SQLServer2014SP1_64bit_rollback.log
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:23:09]i410: Variable: WixBundleSourceProcessFolder = C:\temp\
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:23:09]i410: Variable: WixBundleSourceProcessPath = C:\temp\SQL Setup.exe
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:23:09]i410: Variable: WixBundleTag = 
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:23:09]i410: Variable: WixBundleVersion = 1.0.0.0
[0684:0A34][2016-02-02T15:23:09]i007: Exit code: 0x642, restarting: No
```

Answer (score 1):

`Permanent=yes` means Burn will never uninstall that package.

Comment: I changed `Permanent` to `no`, but nevertheless Burn did no rollback. I tried that with the standard burn gui, but here i get the same result.

Comment: After changing `Permanent` to `no`, I see a line in the log, where Burn is setting the string variable `WixBundleRollbackLog_SQLServer2014SP1_32bit` to a filename. But this file never gets created?

Comment: @roli09 It only rolls back packages that it installed.  I'd have to see the log to say for sure.

Comment: I added the log in my initial post. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @roli09 I guessed right.  It would only to try to rollback the package if it had successfully installed the package.  The log shows that you canceled it before it finished installing the package.